# How to listen to PendingIntent in the new notification builder?

Tags: android

I can create a notification with 3 actions , but I would like to call a method when each of these actions are clicked.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent( this, MainActivity.class );
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0 );

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder( this )
            .setContentTitle( "New mail from " + "test@gmail.com" )
            .setContentText( "Subject" ).setSmallIcon( R.drawable.icon )
            .setContentIntent( pIntent )
            .addAction( R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent )
            .addAction( R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent )
            .addAction( R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent ).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    // hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify( 0, noti );
```

how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Create three separate `Intent` objects, each with an extra or something to distinguish it from the other two

Step #2: Create three separate `PendingIntent` objects, which will require you to use a different solution for the ID than `System.currentTimeMillis()` (since creating three back-to-back may well result in the same millisecond time value)

Step #3: Have each action use its own one of those three `PendingIntent` objects

Step #4: In `onCreate()` and/or `onNewIntent()`, examine the extras of the `Intent` and see which one of the three actions was clicked, and call your desired method

Comment: @user8780097: regarding `"where is the code? stop wasting my time"` -- To be sure, that comment of yours will motivate *many* to help you.